# Why does scipy.ndimage.io.imread return PngImageFile, not an array of values

Tags: python, scipy

I have two different machines with scipy 0.12 and PIL installed. On one machine, when I try to read a .png file, it returns an array of integers with size (w x h x 3):

```
In[2]:  from scipy.ndimage.io import imread
In[3]:  out = imread(png_file)
In[4]:  out.shape
Out[4]: (750, 1000, 4)
```

On the other machine, using the same image file, this returns a `PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile` object wrapped in an array

```
In[2]: from scipy.ndimage.io import imread
In[3]: out = imread(png_file)
In[4]: out.shape
Out[4]: ()
In[5]:  out
Out[5]: array(<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1000x750 at 0x1D40050>, dtype=object)
```

I can't see any way to access the data for the latter object.

I have the vague sense that something is wrong with the way PIL is using Png libraries to read the image, but is there something more specific that would be wrong and cause this behavior?

Comment: I don't see the problem. On the "second computer" when you try the same line (with `.shape` at the end), don't you get the same results?

Comment: In the second case, if that's a 0-D array, you should be able to get at the contents using `thearray.item()` or `thearray[()]`.  Not sure what explains the difference, though.

Comment: I've clarified the question a bit to show that in the second case the returned object is a 0-d object array. Calling thearray.item() doesn't really give me what I want; it just exposes the PngImageFile object directly, but doesn't let me use the image data. the `imread` function is actually just calling array() on this object; this *should* expose the data as a numpy array, but that's not happening for some reason.

Comment: You stated that in both cases scipy is version 0.12 but is PIL the same version in both cases?

Comment: Doing `python -c "import Image; print Image.VERSION"` returns 1.1.7 on both boxes. If there is a different version string for the PIL namespace, I have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's likely that you have an incomplete Python Imaging Library (PIL) install, which SciPy relies on to read the image. PIL relies on the `libjpeg` package to load JPEG images and the `zlib` package to load PNG images, but can be installed without either (in which case it is unable to load whatever images the libraries are missing for).

I had exactly the same issue as you describe above for JPEG images. No error messages are raised, but rather the SciPy call just returns a wrapped PIL object rather than loading the image into an array properly, which makes this particularly tricky to debug. However, when I tried loading in the image using PIL directly, I got:

```
> import Image
> im = Image.open('001988.jpg')
> im
   <JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=333x500 at 0x20C8CB0>
> im.size
> (333, 500)
> pixels = im.load()
   IOError: decoder jpeg not available
```

So I uninstalled my copy of PIL, installed the missing `libjpeg` (in my case, probably `zlib` in yours), reinstalled PIL to register the presence of the library, and now loading images with SciPy works perfectly:

```
> from scipy import ndimage
> im = ndimage.imread('001988.jpg')
> im.shape
   (500, 333, 3)
> im
   array([[[112, 89, 48], ...
                     ..., dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, saved my day. I'm beginning to understand why people still buy Matlab despite of SciPy greatness...

Answer (score 5):

This error (`imread` returning an `PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile` class rather than a data array) often happens when you have older versions of the python imaging library `pillow` or worse still `PIL` installed. `pillow` is an updated "friendly" fork of `PIL` and definitely worth installing!

Try updating these packages; (depending on your python distribution)

```
# to uninstall PIL (if it's there, harmless if not)
$ pip uninstall PIL
# to install (or -U update) pillow
$ pip install -U pillow
```

and then try restarting your python shell and running the commands again.

Answer (score 1):

For the most of use cases, I believe that `libjpeg` or `libz` dependencies are the most probable cause, as mentioned in Ken Chatfield's answer (the one accepted).

I would like to also mention that if someone is experiencing this with under *tensorflow* (especially 0.8.0) --- I mean without tensorflow, PIL did work --- then a similar situation might happen due to a bug of tensorflow.

Some related issues reported in github:

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1924
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1541
- https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2000

A workaround to this would be move `import tensorflow as tf` statement **after** importing `numpy`, `scipy` or `PIL`. Please refer to the aforementioned issues for detailed prescriptions.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solved this issue for me.

What I had to do was to:
downgrade `Pillow` from `5.4.0` to `5.3.0`

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me; even after installing `zlib` and `libjpeg`, the result of

```py
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('2007_000032.png')
print(type(image))
```

was

```py
<class 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'>
```

However,
simply calling:

```py
import numpy as np
image = np.asarray(Image.open('2007_000032.png'))
```

returns the desired data array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
In[2]: from scipy.ndimage.io import imread
In[3]: imread("/hsgs/projects/awagner/test_image.png").shape
```

And tell me what is out ?

Comment: Oh sorry, the shape of the returned object in the "broken" case is (), an empty tuple. I've edited the question to make this more clear.