# Python extension scikit-image error

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am trying to use `scikit-image` to do some research. The system is Windows 7 64bit, and the python version is 2.7, 64bit.

The first program I run is from: http://scikit-image.org/

The code is

```
from skimage import data, io, filter

image = data.coins() # or any NumPy array!
edges = filter.sobel(image)
io.imshow(edges)
io.show()
```

However, the problem happens, and the error message is:

> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\skimage\io_plugins\null_plugin.py:14:
>   RuntimeWarning: No plugin has been loaded.  Please refer to
>
> skimage.io.plugins()
>
> for a list of available plugins.
>   warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(message))

I believe that both `Python` and `scikit-image` are correctly installed. So, may I know what is wrong with it?

Any suggestion is appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Can't reproduce using Python 3.4, Windows 7 64bit, scikit-image v.0.10.1. I'd suggest re-installing scikit-image first and checking you've got the most up to date version.

Answer (score 0):

Just had precisely the same issue on amazon linux. The issue is that skimage requires PIL, and PIL is not installed. In the latest skimage they added the dependency, but the version that I got installed with pip didn't have it yet.

The solution is

```
pip install Pillow
```

EDIT: and after that you will probably immediately face another issue, with skimage loading image, but not being able to read it (in particular, `shape` being empty tuple). Here's the solution

[Why does scipy.ndimage.io.imread return PngImageFile, not an array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036283/why-does-scipy-ndimage-io-imread-return-pngimagefile-not-an-array-of-values)